# Swiftで末尾1文字だけ削除したい

Tags: swift

以下のようなコードを作成しました。[参考](https://qiita.com/yimajo/items/3a55a15c6d74e72026bc)

```
let s = String(repeating: "9,", count: 3)
print(s)
```

出力結果

```
9,9,9,
```

これは、`"9,"`という文字列を繰り返し3回結合しているだけですが
個人的に、最後の末尾の","の文字が不要です。
実際には以下のような出力結果がほしいです。

求めている出力結果

```
9,9,9
```

そこで、末尾1文字を削除したいのですが、どのように削除するとスマートでしょうか？
もしくは末尾の最後を削除しなくても`"9,9,9"`のような文字列を作成するのに適した方法などはありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 最後の1文字を削除する方法

Swift 4 や 5 では `dropLast()` が使えます。

```
let s = String(repeating: "9,", count: 3).dropLast()
```

参考: [Remove last character from string. Swift language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24122288/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

#### 削除をしない方法

他に、`joined` を使う方法もあります。

```
let s = Array(repeating: "9", count: 3).joined(separator: ",")
```